# How to create a data.frame that counts how many instances by date in R

Tags: r, dataframe, lubridate

greatly appreciated if anyone could help with creating a vector that counts the total number of records per day.

As the pre-requisite, the question requires extracting the date from a CSV file (in this format: 11/05/2015 01:30) and I used lubridate to performed that already.

```
library(lubridate)
x<-df$hour_id
x
lubridate::mdy_hm(x)
as.Date(lubridate::mdy_hm(x))
```

I was able to get the vector as dates as follow:

```
 [741] "2015-11-23" "2015-11-23" "2015-11-23" "2015-11-23" "2015-11-23" "2015-11-23" "2015-11-23" "2015-11-23" "2015-11-23" "2015-11-23"
 [751] "2015-11-23" "2015-11-23" "2015-11-23" "2015-11-23" "2015-11-23" "2015-11-23" "2015-11-24" "2015-11-24" "2015-11-24" "2015-11-24"
 [761] "2015-11-24" "2015-11-24" "2015-11-24" "2015-11-24" "2015-11-24" "2015-11-24" "2015-11-24" "2015-11-24" "2015-11-24" "2015-11-24"
```

I need some assistance to create data.frame with two columns: Date and total count of the date

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
table(x)
```

this would give you the unique values and its counts in the vector
like this

```
2015-11-23 2015-11-24 
         5          5
```

Then you could just

```
as.data.frame(table(x))
```

```
           x Freq
1 2015-11-23    5
2 2015-11-24    5
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be useful if you provided the `df` data frame using `dput(df)`.

Here is a simple version with just the column you mentioned:

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- tibble(hour_id = c("11/05/2015 01:30", "11/01/2015 01:30", "12/05/2015 01:30", "12/05/2015 01:30"))
```

This this code gives what you want:

```
df %>% 
  mutate(date = lubridate::mdy_hm(hour_id) %>% lubridate::as_date()) %>% 
  count(date)

# A tibble: 3 x 2
  date           n
  <date>     <int>
1 2015-11-01     1
2 2015-11-05     1
3 2015-12-05     2
```